# Missing Globalization Cultures on IIS8.5 / Server 2012R2

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-8, globalization

I'm trying to set the culture of a website to `en-ZM` in the `web.config` of the site but I get an error:

`The <globalization> tag contains an invalid value for the 'culture' attribute.`

When I try to set it via IIS' interface, it seems Zambia isn't listed in the available options, although other African countries like Zimbabwe are (`en-ZW`).

**Example of the .NET Globalization UI in IIS 8.5 on server 1 (Windows Server 2012R2):**
[image: Note the lack of Zambia as an option]

**Example of the .NET Globalization UI in IIS 10 on server 2 (Windows Server 2016):**
[image: Zambia is included as an option here]

My local machine is running Win10 and has this culture available for configuration so I hadn't expected this to be an issue. Is there any update I can manually install to add the missing cultures?

Comment: can you show me your web.confug file? or you can refer to this link: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh831368(v=ws.11)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh831368(v=ws.11)).

Comment: @samwu this doesn't seem a web.config issue, the culture does not exist on server 1 but does on server 2. I've updated the question to show the examples. I suspect there's a language pack or update that will resolve this but have no clue where to start. Unfortunately upgrading the OS on server 1 is not possible

Comment: It may be a problem with your iis version, one is IIS 8.5 and the other is IIS 10.

Comment: I think that's quite obvious @samwu - the version of IIS shouldn't limit what language packs are supported on the OS. Thanks anyway, I'll raise a ticket with MS